# Basis for complement of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

Consider we have a vector space $V$ with a given basis $\{v_i\}_{i \in I}$, and a subspace $U$. Show that we can always find a subset $J \subset I$ such that $\{v_i\}_{i \in J}$ is a basis for a complement of $U$ in $V$. For me intuitively it is clear but I cannot make it rigorous. By a complement $W$ of $U$ in $V$ I mean a subspace $W \subset V$ such that $V=U + W$ and $U \cap W =\{0\}$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No. It can have higher cardinality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of those subsets $J$ of $I$ such that its $\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_i\mid i\in I\}\bigr)\cap W=\{0\}$. You can deduce from Zorn's lemma that $\mathcal F$ has a maximal element $M$. Then $\{v_i\mid i\in M\}$ is a basis of a complement of $W$ in $V$.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and it works I think. Could you please also suggest how I can argue in finite dimensional case?

Comment: The same way, except that now you would not need to use Zorn's lemma, since $\mathcal F$ would be finite now.